# How to use Kde connect to "add devices by IP"?

Tags: 17.04, kde-connect

I am trying to connect my android phone to pc. But generally my phone is not detected. I donot have any firewall enabled. Eventhen KDE connect is not showing my device.

How can I connect my android device by "ADD DEVICES BY IP " option. How to use it. How to find which IP to keep?

Comment: how to find phone IP address

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find your device IP

There are multiple ways to find your device IP, you can check them out [here](https://www.howtouselinux.com/post/check-ip-address-in-linux).

For me I used:

```bsh
ip add
```

and here was my output:

```bsh
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx brd xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp4s0
       valid_lft 603698sec preferred_lft 603698sec
    inet6 yyyy::yyy:yyyy:yyyy:yyy/yy scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

You want the one marked **inet** with the value of the IP next to it.

For example your int value can be: 192.168.0.0/21

Take that value with the / and add it in your KDE connect app under Add devices by IP.